# Create relative URL from two absolutes (WinAPI)

Tags: windows, winapi, url, url-parsing

Is there a method to create a relativeURL from two absolute ones (assumingthey have the same base / domain)

e.g.

```
MakeRelative("http://foo/1.html", "http://foo/img/2.png") 
--> "./img/2.png"

MakeRelative("http://foo/1.html", "http://bar/img/2.png") 
--> fails
```

.NET has `System.URI.MakeRelativeURI`, I'm looking for a native equivalent.

I hoped to find something i the [Shell Lightweight Utilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but no luck. I could probably hack together something with those funcitons or basic string manipulation, but I'm not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3507.html

Answer (score 0):

There is the win32 function [`PathRelativePathTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for creating a relative path from one file system location to another.  Good documentation on MSDN too.